# Rails attempting to throttle my API with rack-attack. Unsure if it's working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

This is my [repo](https://github.com/Jwan622/rails_api_practice/tree/master/ams_api_practice)

I just added the rack-attack gem.

```
gem 'rack-attack'
```

And this is my app/initializers/rack-attack.rb file:

```
class Rack::Attack

  Rack::Attack.cache.store = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new

  whitelist('allow-localhost') do |req|
    '127.0.0.1' == req.ip || '::1' == req.ip
  end

  throttle('req/ip', limit: 10, period: 10) do |req|
    req.ip
  end

  self.throttled_response = ->(env) {
    retry_after = (env['rack.attack.match_data'] || {})[:period]
    [
      429,
      {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Retry-After' => retry_after.to_s},
      [{error: "Throttle limit reached. Retry later."}.to_json]
    ]
  }
end
```

This is my application.rb file:

```
module ApiCodeship
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Only loads a smaller set of middleware suitable for API only apps.
    # Middleware like session, flash, cookies can be added back manually.
    # Skip views, helpers and assets when generating a new resource.
    config.api_only = true
    config.middleware.use Rack::Attack
  end
end
```

When I visit http://localhost:3000/rental_units, this is my logs in my console:

```
Started GET "/rental_units" for ::1 at 2016-03-03 23:01:32 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by RentalUnitsController#index as HTML
  RentalUnit Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "rental_units".* FROM "rental_units"
[active_model_serializers] Dalli::Server#connect localhost:11211
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers]   User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer with ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter::JsonApi (44.37ms)
Completed 200 OK in 62ms (Views: 57.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

How do I know I'm throttling correctly?

Comment: Note the "Testing" on Rack-Attack github readme. It says that you need somehow cache your development environment to be able to "test".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have recently been implementing rack attack inside my application. I found a couple of really helpful blog posts about testing Rack::Attack.

Essentially the below advise that you install the `gem 'rack-test'`

You can then `include Rack::Test::Methods` at the top of an rspec file which will enable you to write tests such as;

```
describe 'throttling urls' do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Rails.application
  end

  describe 'throttle excessive requests by IP address' do
  let(:limit) { 10 }

    context 'number of requests is lower than the limit' do
      it "does not chnage the request status" do
        limit.times do
          get '/show', {}, "REMOTE_ADDR" => "1.2.3.4"
          expect(last_response.status).to_not eq 429
        end
      end
    end

    context 'number of requests is higher than the limit' do
      it 'changes the request status to 429' do
        (limit * 2).times do |i|
          get '/show', {}, "REMOTE_ADDR" => "1.2.3.5"
          expect(last_response.status).to eq(429) if i > limit
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The blogs i followed were;

[Great blog post if using the old rspec syntax](http://www.mavengineering.com/blog/2014/06/20/how-to-test-rack-attack-with-rspec/)

[More recent blog about testing rack attack but slightly less detailed](http://blog.hayleyanderson.us/2015/06/05/using-and-testing-rack-attack-to-improve-the-security-of-your-rails-app/)

Answer (score 5):

Probably development rails server should start caching.
In file development.rb change:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
```

to

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

And restart server. After 10 + 1 requests to your throttled route you will receive expected block/throttle.

Answer (score 2):

By default rails development cache is disable.

Should be enable in the console with `rails dev:cache` in order for Rack Attack to start working.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this question, but there is an example on how to achieve exponential backoff here: https://github.com/rack/rack-attack/blob/main/docs/advanced_configuration.md#exponential-backoff

```
# Allows 20 requests in 8  seconds
#        40 requests in 64 seconds
#        ...
#        100 requests in 0.38 days (~250 requests/day)
(1..5).each do |level|
  throttle("logins/ip/#{level}", :limit => (20 * level), :period => (8 ** level).seconds) do |req|
    if req.path == '/login' && req.post?
      req.ip
    end
  end
end
```